# Obscure Names in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

I recently stumbled over the "Happy Ending Problem" (cf e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Ending_problem), which made we wonder, if there are other conjectures, theorems or problems, whose names do not give any indication to what they are about or, to which person it is related;
the "kissing number" would not qualify here, because it is a definition, but neither a problem nor a theorem.

Besides the "Happy Ending Theorem", I also found

- the "No-Ghost Theorem" (cf e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goddard%E2%80%93Thorn_theorem) in the context of "Monstrous Moonshine".
- the "Mother Worm Problem" (cf e.g. http://citation.allacademic.com/meta/p_mla_apa_research_citation/2/0/7/8/9/p207895_index.html?phpsessid=a0a1836d9b5ca905a3cff4af0fa64752)
- the "Dining Philosophers Problem" (cf e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)

Comment: I thought Happy Ending referred to something completely different.

Comment: This doesn't need to be closed quickly (unless it's a duplicate)
but should be made community wiki.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies since MO 2.0 questions can't be made community wiki by the author (see the answer to this Meta post: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1713/where-is-the-community-wiki)

Comment: voted to close because it's nowhere near research level. I'm not sure whether or not this is on-topic at math.SE because I don't know enough about that site.

Comment: The Dining Philosophers Problem seems to have some relation to the Byzantine Generals Problem, http://marknelson.us/2007/07/23/byzantine/

Comment: The Soul Theorem is one that comes to mind.

Comment: @WillJagy: See also the [Going Down Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down#Going-up_and_going-down_theorems).

Comment: You could argue to some extent about Pell's equations. Pell had nothing to do with them.

Comment: In which case add "Platonic solids".

Comment: Oh _come on_ - if we are going to add theorems named after the wrong people then we will be here all day...

Comment: Yes, I believe that's known as Yemon's Observation.

Comment: I propose *Myerson's Observation*:  "If we are going to add theorems named after the wrong people then we will be here all day."

Comment: The [thirty-six officers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_officers_problem) problem.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if all these give "no clue", but they are somewhat obscure clues:

[The Law of the Unconscious Statistician.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

[The Chinese Postman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem)

[The Googol Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) (aka the Secretary Problem)

[The Butterfly Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_lemma) and [The Snake Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma)

[The Art Gallery Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem) (or Problem)

and for those who know some Latin:

[Theorema Egregium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium) and [Pons Asinorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum)

Comment: as this is a soft question, all of these are acceptable to me

Comment: The Tomato Can principle.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Gauß has a theorema aureum, too. André Weil even wrote once something like, "he [the Princeps Mathematicorum] was very fond of this type of names"...

Answer (score 15):

[The Ham Sandwich Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem)

[The Hungarian Method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

[The Hairy Ball Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)

[The Konigsberg Bridge Problem.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KoenigsbergBridgeProblem.html)

[The St. Petersburg Paradox.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)

[The Futurama Theorem.](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/Futurama.shtml)

Comment: The Basel problem. The Monte Carlo method.

Comment: not to forget the Las Vegas method

Comment: The Pancake Problems, http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/openp/pancake.html

Comment: +1 for The Hungarian method, as I'm actually using it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether God's Algorithm (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185090/what-is-gods-number-for-the-wrapslide-puzzle) qualifies.

Answer (score 12):

[The Ten Martini Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503363) was a conjecture posed by Kac and Simon and answered by Avila and Jitomirskaya.

Answer (score 11):

[The Killing-Hopf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing-Hopf_theorem) (yes, Hopf is already dead).

[The ugly duckling theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_duckling_theorem)

[The no free lunch theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)

[The Cox-Zucker machine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox-Zucker_machine)

Comment: For a layman hearing ‘Cox-Zucker’ for the first time, it might take on a whole different meaning.

Comment: "problems, whose names do not give any indication to what they are about or, to which person it is related...." Do Killing-Hopf and Cox-Zucker qualify?

Comment: In the strict sense: no, but let's be generous

Comment: Similar to the Killing-Hopf theorem, the Italian name for the Gaussian elimination method sounds like someone is debating on the best way to kill poor C.F. Gauss.

Answer (score 3):

The Busy Beaver Problem.

The Beer Glass Theorem.

The Garden of Eden Theorem.

Comment: After posting this, I tried to StartPage "beer glass theorem" and couldn't find anything, so maybe it's not so well known by that name. Too bad, it would be a nice accompaniment to the Ham Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: The Beer Glass Theorem says that, if three congruent circles in the plane intersect at one point, then the circle determined by the other three intersections is congruent to the original circle. Is there another name for this theorem?

Comment: I mentioned the Byzantine Generals in an earlier comment on the original post.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Dagnabbit! I searched the page for "Byzantine" but I forgot to click on "show more comments". I will delete the generals from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pigeonhole (or Box) Principle.  (Note that "rational box problem" is very different from "Box principle".)

Jugendtraum (as with Dirichlet for the Pigeonhole Principle, 
 the name of Kronecker is sometimes omitted).

Answer (score 2):

[Hauptvermutung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung)

Technically this is a conjecture, but there are results about whether it is true or not under various circumstances.

Comment: That meets the kriterion of obscurity and not being a definition (if the conjecture were proven, it would be a theorem).

Answer (score 2):

[Tropical geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry)

[Margulis napkin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_folding_problem)

[Traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

[Canadian traveller problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_traveller_problem)

Comment: Speaking of tropical geometry: the Aztec diamond and the arctic circle theorem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond ).

Comment: And speaking of Aztec diamond, Cairo pentagonal tilings.

Comment: "problems, whose names do not give any indication to what they are about or, to which person it is related...." Does the Margulis napkin problem qualify?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Maybe I should use the Wikipedia name, "napkin folding problem."  But then maybe the objection is that "folding" is a clue to what it is about.

Answer (score 2):

[The master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

For a theorem whose name is actually misleading about its actual content, check out the case of the *Diversity trumps ability theorem*, as described by Abigail Thompson in a recent Notices: http://www.ams.org/notices/201409/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Hauptsatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) (due to Gentzen).

Answer (score 0):

The [Stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). $ $

Comment: The Stable Marriage problem (or theorem) is about the stability of marriage, isn't it?

Comment: I guess, though that sort of objection applies to lots of other answers here too (e.g., the Traveling Salesman problem is about a traveling salesman).